# Is there a way to create a Windows virtual machine on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, windows, virtualization

When I look for documentation about how to create a Windows VM on an Ubuntu host, the only articles I can find are articles about Ubuntu Desktop, not Ubuntu Server.

Is there a way to create a Windows VM on Ubuntu Server? Can anyone point me to any articles? Bonus points if I don't need to compile anything or do anything super complex.

Comment: If you already know how to use KVM on the command line, just `sudo tasksel install virt-host`, and you will have everything ready for full-blown server for virtualization.

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests) is quite enough to tell you how to get started with KVM on the command line. To access the VMs, just use VNC. If you need any more explanation, comment and tag me `@Oxwivi`, I will make a full answer.

Answer (score 14):

You should use KVM, because ... because Ubuntu love Kvm

**what is KVM**

KVM (for Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a full virtualization solution for Linux on x86 hardware containing virtualization extensions (Intel VT or AMD-V).

Using KVM, one can run multiple virtual machines running unmodified Linux or Windows images. Each virtual machine has private virtualized hardware: a network card, disk, graphics adapter, etc.

The kernel component of KVM is included in mainline Linux, as of 2.6.20.

Ubuntu uses KVM as the back-end virtualization for non-graphic servers and libvirt as its toolkit/API. Libvirt front ends for managing VMs include virt-manager (GUI).

**Let's go to hack**

This setup guide is to configure a KVM on Ubuntu Server and management of the VMs is done remotely from another machine running Ubuntu Desktop.

*SERVER SIDE*

STEP #1: Install lib-virt package.

```
sudo apt-get install kvm libvirt-bin
```

STEP #2:allow incoming tcp and udp packet on port 22 (ssh) on server

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

*DESKTOP SIDE*

STEP #2: Install Virtual Machine Manager (on Ubuntu Desktop machine).

```
sudo apt-get install virt-manager
```

STEP #3: Connect to the server: execute virt-manager

```
gksudo virt-manager
```

- FILE.
- ADD Connection.

  - Connect to remote computer
  - Method : SSH
  - User : your user server
  - machine name : ip address of the server

NOW YOU ARE READY TO CREATE VIRTUAL MACHINE ON THE SERVER

STEP #4: Create the Guest VM image. Virtual Machine Manager provides a GUI to easily create an image. Just right-click on the server and select “New”. You will then be prompted step-by-step on the variables (e.g. # of processors, memory, etc.) needed to be configured for your VM.

STEP #5: Install the Guest VM OS. Use your regular CD/DVD installer or iso image to install the operating system on the VM.

More information in ubuntu official server Documentation -> [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/libvirt.html)

Good Luck and Happy Rocking

**P.S : you souldn't be afraid of command line.....**

Comment: Not afraid of the command line (I actually kinda love it), I just hate the complex stuff that usually causes errors that I have to google for hours to troubleshoot.

Comment: Just keeps asking me for my servers root password - over and over and over :/

Answer (score 5):

VirtualBox (what you'll have been reading about in the desktop threads) has a few command line tools that allow you to run any virtual machine in a headless state.

An example would be:

```
VBoxHeadless -startvm vm_name
```

You would still need to set up the VM which can be done, I believe, with `VBoxManage` (`VBoxManage --help` for options there). It might be easiest to do initial configuration on a desktop and then transfer the config and disk image to the server.

If you want it to run on boot, you'd want to write an init or Upstart script for it to load, or just shove the command in /etc/rc.local as a lazy, unmanaged method (you'll probably want `&` on the end of the command so it doesn't block the system loading).

But similarly, you might have to use Upstart so it doesn't load up until networking has come up. Play around with it and let us know what works.

But you shouldn't need to compile anything.

Edit: There are some [run-on-boot suggestions in this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=6663).

Edit 2: There are some [old installation instructions here](http://www.howtoforge.com/vboxheadless-running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-2.0-on-a-headless-ubuntu-8.04-server) but what is really useful there are the example VBoxManage statements:

> ```
> VBoxManage createvm -name "Ubuntu 8.04 Server" -register
> VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 8.04 Server" -memory "256MB" -acpi on -boot1 dvd -nic1 nat
> VBoxManage createvdi -filename "Ubuntu_8_04_Server.vdi" -size 10000 -register
> VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 8.04 Server" -hda "Ubuntu_8_04_Server.vdi"
> VBoxManage registerimage dvd /home/ubuntu-8.04.1-server-i386.iso
> VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 8.04 Server" -dvd /home/ubuntu-8.04.1-server-i386.iso
> ```

You'll need to customise them for your situation but they should give you a good reference point.

Comment: official virtualbox documentation vboxmanage -> https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html

Comment: @Oli ♦ Hmm what did you mean by headless state?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Lee Headless means without a monitor. Most people manage their servers remotely without any sort of connected display.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask if you need open-source/free software or commercial.

This is a good commercial solution I am personally using:

http://www.vbridges.com

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Not all commercial software is evil, just the stuff from Redmond and Cupertino.

Comment: @Oli Redmond ain't that bad. Don't hate.

Comment: I was joking! Blimey. Everybody is taking me too seriously today :)

Comment: Well I didn't say anything about Cupertino... ;)

Comment: haters gona hate..

Comment: @Oli I'm willing to bet the issue isn't that it's commercial, but rather, that it's proprietary. Lots of people, OP and yourself included, have confused the terms.